# Use variable in recursive search and stop once file is copied

Tags: batch-file, recursion, xcopy

I have the following batch script that takes in a list of files and recursively goes through and tries to copy the file:

```
        for /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in (Files.txt) do 
    ( (for /R "\\network\Sites\" %%f in (%%x) do 
(echo F | xcopy /i "%%f" C:\Files\ )) )
```

The above does work, but it loops through all subfolders even after the file is copied, which takes about 25 minutes and is not a feasible solution given the number of files that need to be copied.  I've updated the input file to include an additional part of the file structure that changes for each file to limit the number of folders that need to be searched like this:

```
for /f "delims=, tokens=1,2" %%x in (new2.csv) do 
( (for /R "\\network\Sites\%%x\Analyzed\" %%f in (%%y) do 
(echo F | xcopy /i "%%f" C:\Files\ )) )
```

The issue is that it doesn't populate the `%%x` variable from the csv file, it just runs the command with using the path `\\network\Sites\%x\Analyzed\` but the `%%y` variable is populated correctly with the file name.

Is there anyway to get that to populate?  Is there a better way to recursively search for a file and copy it than what I am doing above (using `for /r`)?

Also, is there anyway to get the script to proceed to the next file once it has been successfully copied by xcopy?

I've been looking around for similar questions, but none of the solutions seem to work in my case.

EDIT:  Including more information per request.

The problem I'm trying to solve is I have a list of files that need to be copied from a UNC path.  The issue is that doing the naive approach of just recursing through all subfolders in the main directory (`\\network\Sites\`) and attempting to copy the file takes approx. 25 minutes per file due to the number of directories that are being searched, making it a non-feasible solution due to the number of files that need to be copied.

`files.txt` is just a list of filenames with extensions separated by a newline e.g.

`123hsdfs.ext
4t5efrre.ext`

In the second attempt, `new2.csv` was an approach where I attempted to pull an additional portion of the expected directory in the file list to cut down on the number of subfolders the script had to search through.  The file would contain something like the following:

`001,123hsdfs.ext
002,4t5efrre.ext`

I attempted to put `001` and `002` into the `for /r` loop, but when executed the variable wasn't populated properly.  Where I expected when searching for `123hsdfs.ext` the recursion loop would use the root folder `\\network\Sites\001\Analyzed\` it was using `\\network\Sites\%x\Analyzed\`.

So, the problem I'm trying to solve is two part:

1) How can I cut down the number of subfolders that are searched through when part of the directory can change per file (Ideally would be to only recursively search in the `Analyzed` directory within each subdirectory of `\\network\Sites` e.g. search in `\\network\Sites\001\Analyzed`, `\\network\Sites\002\Analyzed` etc. as using the `.csv` approach is significantly more work)?

2) How can I proceed to the next file in the list once the current file is successfully copied so I'm not needlessly searching folders for it?

Comment: Please describe the problem you are trying to solve. We have to make too many assumptions form analying your code and the result is a guessing-game. I conclude you want to search a directory-subtree for a file and copy the first instance found, but you've provided no example in either `new2.csv` or `files.txt`. Please show some sample data.

Comment: @Magoo Additional information has been added.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in (Files.txt) do (
 for /R "\\network\Sites\" %%f in (%%x) do (
   echo F | xcopy /i "%%f" C:\Files\ && (
     goto :break
   )
  ) 
)
:break
```

to break only outer loop use subroutine.Internal loop still has access to the tokens of outer even wrapped in subroutine or in batch file:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in (Files.txt) do (
   call :internal
)
exit /b 0

:internal
 for /R "\\network\Sites\" %%f in (%%x) do (
   echo F | xcopy /i "%%f" C:\Files\ && (
     goto :break
   )
  ) 
:break
exit /b 0
```

goto breaks the `for` context and be used to terminate its execution.

Comment: This breaks the whole script after the first file is found and copied.  I tried putting `:break` at the top of the script, but every time a file is found and copied it starts at the top of the list again in `Files.txt`.  Is there anyway to get it to continue with the next entry in `Files.txt` when a file is copied successfully?

Comment: Unfortunately this gives the same issue as the second script in the OP where it's using `%x` instead of the filename from the text file.

Answer (score 0):

You need `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`; however, for it to work right, you need regular variables to hold the values during each loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%x in (new2.csv) do (
  set x=%%x
  for /R "\\network\Sites\!x!\Analyzed\" %%f in (%%y) do (
    set f=%%f
    xcopy /i "!f!" C:\Files\
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q28480130.txt) DO SET "$%%a=Y"
FOR /r "%sourcedir%" %%a IN (*.*) DO (
 SET "left="
 FOR /f "delims==" %%w IN ('set $') DO IF /i "%%w"=="$%%~nxa" (
  ECHO found %%~fa
  SET "%%w="
  XCOPY /i "%%~fa" "%destdir%\" >nul
 ) ELSE (SET "left=Y")
 IF NOT DEFINED left GOTO done
)
echo these file not found
set $
:done
ECHO all done
DIR %destdir%

GOTO :EOF
```

This could work for you.

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q28480130.txt` containing this data for my testing

```
123hsdfs.ext
4t5efrre.ext
gx112 juf.lgmm
pq72-99!.kut
ttyopd
$92k.opz
```

The process first clear all environment variables starting `$`.

Then set an environment variable `$filename` for each filename in the file.

Then read the source directory, filename-by-filename and see whether $filename is `set` in the environment. If it is, clear it from the environment and copy the file (I left the options the same and obviated the `echo` by using a trailing `\`)

`left` is first cleared in each loop, then set if there is any mismatch between the "filenames" set in the environment and the filename found (as a mismatch implies a file-not-yet-found.) Consequently, if `left` remains undefined when the `for..%%w` is finished, then the last $filename has just been found and deleted from the environment, so we can terminate the process.

If there are any names not found, then these wil be listed by the conventional exit from the `for...%%a` loop. They'll be prefixed by `$`. Easily dealt with and left as a small exercise for anyone interested.